# Three.js dashed circle

Tags: javascript, three.js

Following the pattern for dashed line, I tried this, but it doesn't give me a dashed circle (not that surprising).

```
var dashMaterial = new THREE.LineDashedMaterial( { color: 0xee6666, dashSize: 0.5, gapSize: 0.5  } ),
circGeom = new THREE.CircleGeometry( 10, 20 );
circGeom.computeLineDistances();
circGeom.vertices.shift();
var circ = new THREE.Line( circGeom, dashMaterial);
scene.add( circ );
```

How to construct a dashed circle in Three.js?

Answer (score 2):

You must compute distances between vertices after remove central vertex:

```
circGeom.computeLineDistances();
circGeom.vertices.shift();
```

=>

```
circGeom.vertices.shift();
circGeom.computeLineDistances();
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/fs904hon/ ]

Comment: Your result looks a bit weird. The linepieces seem a bit distorted. Are you sure the result is correct?

Comment: My result answers the question of topic starter: why the code which he showed not display a dashed circle. Of course, if we play the following parameters: the number of segments of a circle, the dashed line configuration, we can get better results [ https://jsfiddle.net/56sqt3rq/ ]

Comment: Thanks, stdob. The settings in your second fiddle worked great. It seems I can't vote for your answer yet, but thank you!